# Magento - Update Cart From Custom PHP FIle

Tags: jquery, magento, post, cart

I need to be able to update the quantity of products in the user cart from a custom PHP file I'm posting to via jQuery's post function. I'm trying to use Magento's functions but I only get a blank page. Does anybody know how to update the cart data?

This is what returns a blank page...

```
<?php
include_once '/app/Mage.php';
$test = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData(); 
var_dump($test);
?>
```

Comment: I don't think you want to include '/app/Mage.php', unless Magento really is installed in your root ('/').

Comment: Magento is installed in the htdocs folder.

Comment: If your PHP script is located in the same folder then do `require_once 'app/Mage.php';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try this script out inside your magento folder (where index.php is located) so that the include path is relative,

Secondly:

```
<?php
    require_once "app/Mage.php";
    Mage::app('default'); // initialize -the- app so you could access the singletons (like sessions, quotes, etc);
    $test = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData();  // load the cart singleton 
    var_dump($test);

    // take note that there isn't a closing PHP tag.. just observing the Zend Coding standards
```

Also in dealing with session-related singletons (cart, quote) you might want to get and restore the session ID (if known). Bear in mind that testing from your custom PHP file and testing from the actual magento app yields different SID's. You must provide a way to 'share' it in between somehow. Insert the following after `Mage:app();`:

```
$frontend = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$frontend->setSessionId($sid);
```

Comment: I'm having an issue with getAllVisibleItems() returning an empty array despite having items in the cart. Any ideas why?


    `require_once "../../app/Mage.php";
     Mage::app('default');
     $frontend = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
     $frontend->setSessionId($sid);
          
     $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
     $cart->init();
          
     $cartItems = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();`

Comment: did you actually set $sid to something?